# Operator overloading the stream extraction operator (>>) in C++ results in infinite recursive stream extraction

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm still learning my way around C++ (I am a high school student) and for a competition I need to read in comma separated values, and I thought it would be a neat opportunity to learn how to overload the stream extraction (>>) operator to get rid of any delimiters that may come after a value. (This is the best way I could think of, if there are any better, please share!) However, as the title says, the stream extraction operation recurses infinitely, causing the program to crash. I have no idea how to fix this and I tried searching online for a solution for hours. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std; // Sorry if this annoys some people

// Create a class the inherits from ifstream for file opening and stream extraction and stuff. (cStream stands for Custom Stream)
class cStream : public ifstream
{
private:
    string Delimiters;
public:
    cStream() : ifstream() {}
    cStream(const char* filename, const char* _Delimiters = "\n\t\0") : ifstream(filename), Delimiters(_Delimiters) {}

    // Define friend functions so that the stream extractor can access the private variable Delimiters. (might not be needed but eh)
    template <class t>  friend cStream& operator >> (cStream&, t&); // Problem function.
};

cStream& operator >> (cStream in, const char* delimOverride)
{
    in.Delimiters = delimOverride;

    return(in);
}

// Operator overloaded stream extractor that gets rid of any characters in cStream.Delimiters.
// The variable names are weird but I didn't know what to name them.
template <class t> cStream& operator >> (cStream& in, t& out)
{
    in >> out; // What the heck do I do here?
    // The cStream stream extraction operator gets called recursively because it takes a cStream and returns a cStream,
    // but how do I fix that...?

    // Get rid of any trailing delimiters and spaces
    while ((in.Delimiters + " ").find(in.peek()) != -1) in.ignore();

    //Return with new input stream
    return(in);
}
```

I don't know if this is bad code or not, as I said, I'm still learning about C++. If it is bad code, please help me improve it. Thank you! <3

I'm also a noob to Stack Overflow so if I did anything wrong, please tell!

Comment: Probably don't want to use inheritance like that.

Comment: @NeilButterworth please elaborate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> in >> out; // What the heck do I do here?
> ```

That line of code is translated as `operator>>(in, out)`, which leads to infinite recursion.

I am guessing you want to read to `out` using the base class functionality. For that, you need to explicity create a reference to the base class and use that reference.

```
std::ifstream& in_f = in;
in_f >> out;
```

You may also use a one-liner.

```
static_cast<std::ifstream&>(in) >> out;
```

Comment: Wow thank you! That is exactly what I needed. I didn't know you could cast to base class using `ifstream& base = derived`. The `&` part came as a surprise, I was trying to cast the cStream object without it a few researches ago.

Comment: @Freddy, glad I was able to help.